# JodaTime not parsing what it should parse?

Tags: java, parsing, date, jodatime, strptime

This throws an Invalid format exception:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("%E, %d %M %Y %H:%m:%s %z").parseMillis("Sun, 20 May 2012 01:07:11 +0000")
```

Why doesn't it work? According to [the spec](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern%28java.lang.String%29), it seems like it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the pattern should be more like:

```
EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of that your `z` parameter is wrong. It should be PST, for example.
Either capitalize it (use `Z`) or change the input string.